# C++/CLI is Application unable to Start

Tags: c++, c, c++-cli

I have Created a C++/CLI Console Application and I am using C Static Library(Multi-threaded (/MT)) In it.
Its Compiling fine but, when I try  to launch it is showing Message Box 
Saying

Unable to start ....\ManagedSample.exe

THis application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect.    Review the manifets file for possible error.

I have Set clr option.

Comment: Use a project template to get your project started.  That ensures that the required manifest is automatically generated and embedded in your program.  Pick the appropriate one from the Visual C++, CLR node.

Comment: @Hans Any Idea Why THis Problem is coming??

Comment: Chris, do you get this when running the app on your dev machine, or on a different one?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: What CPU are you targetting with your C++/CLI project and what processr has the C static library been built for? Could it be that you're trying to run the managed code on an x64 CPU but the static library is built for x86?

Comment: If you're using the static library with C++/CLI, you need to use `/MD`/`/MDd`, not `/MT`.

Comment: I am using BS 2010 and running x86 machine and static library is built using /MDd option.

Comment: @Chris : If that's true then that's your problem -- don't distribute debug builds. Build your static lib in release mode (with `/MD`) and do the same with your C++/CLI app, then as long as the other computer has the VC++ redist installed (as linked to in Simon's answer) you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this happens when no or the wrong C++ runtime library is installed.
Download and install the correct VC++ redist.

Eg. if you built your application with VS2010 SP1 use [this package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328).